# post data changing on submit

Tags: php, html, forms, post

When I submit data in my form it changes "abcd" to  \"abcd\" on the other end.How can I overcome this problem... (I am using post method to send data).....
Please help...Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is generally due to magic_quotes.

Something similar to

```
<?php
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    function stripslashes_deep($value)
    {
        $value = is_array($value) ?
                    array_map('stripslashes_deep', $value) :
                    stripslashes($value);

        return $value;
    }

    $_POST = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $_POST);
    $_GET = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $_GET);
    $_COOKIE = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $_COOKIE);
    $_REQUEST = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $_REQUEST);
}
?>
```

Should switch them off. I'd reccomend switching them off in your configuration though..

https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php

Answer (score 0):

That are probably [Magic Quotes](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php). You can disable them by disabling [`magic_quotes_gpc`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc) (either [in a .htaccess file](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php#configuration.changes.apache) or in the server configuration).

Comment: It *can* be disabled in a .htaccess file if PHP runs as Apache module. The *Changeable* value of `magic_quotes_gpc` is *PHP_INI_PERDIR* (see http://docs.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php).